# Launch exe/bat on remote server with PowerShell (not copy content to my server)

Tags: powershell, batch-file, remote-server

I found the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet in PowerShell that supposedly is invoking a command on another server but this doesn't quite work. Instead what I get is the print of what the bat/exe. My exe is a console app and the bat was a test I did that launches the exe with `start "" "myexe.exe"`.

This is the command I'm trying to do:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 10.10.10.10 -ScriptBlock {
    'C:\Program Files\program.exe'
}
```

or

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 10.10.10.10 -ScriptBlock {
    'C:\Program Files\batch.bat'
}
```

In both cases instead of the command getting invoked on the other server I get the print on the server I call from.

Did I miss an argument somewhere? I want to launch the exe/bat on the remote server, not on the server I'm on.

## EDIT

I made it work with this:

```
$command = "PathtoExe.exe"
$process = [WMICLASS]"\\10.10.10.10\ROOT\CIMV2:win32_process"
$result = $process.Create($command)
```

But now the exe is not displayed, it's like running in the background.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Please elaborate on what doesn't work the way you expected. `Inovke-Command` invokes a scriptblock on a remote host and returns the output of that commands in that scriptblock to the local machine. When using the `-FilePath` parameter you can generate the scriptblock from a local (PowerShell) script. You cannot invoke a local executable on a remote computer without copying it to that computer first (or invoking it from a shared folder).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I want to execute that exe/bat on the remote server and not on the server where i execute invoke-command. Example i execute invok-command on my server which is 10.10.10.9 and the command is set to launch an exe on 10.10.10.10

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is how you're trying to call the executable.  In PowerShell, *everything is an object*.  What you're doing is printing the `String` to the console instead of executing.  To invoke the string, you need to use the call operator: `&`

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 10.10.10.10 -ScriptBlock {
    & 'C:\Program Files\batch.bat'
}
```

This will cause it to use the default program for that extension.

Comment: This still shows me the output on the server where i'm calling the command. It doesn't launch the exe on the 10.10.10.10

Comment: Of course it's going to show you the output on your server, that's the point. @John

Comment: But i want to launch the actual exe on the server

Comment: @John You *are*.  It's redirecting the program output to your console with `Invoke-Command`

Comment: The exe i'm calling is a rest service that stays open and waits for rest commands. Does invoke command forcefully close the exe?

Comment: It shouldn't be, but if you're worried about that happening, open a session to leave open and test it out.  Look into the `*-PSSession` cmdlets. @John

Comment: I have the two servers open and i don't see the app i'm calling getting open that's why. I found that there's a "Start-process" aswell, when i do this i see that there is 1 more process that gets triggered but it's closed right after

Comment: If i check eventvwr there's no commandline being sent is that normal?

Comment: @John It *should* be, but I can't remember if that's a default.  You can configure script logging

Comment: I'm really sorry to bother you man, I've found a solution can you check my edit to the question? The app now is somewhere in the background

Comment: @John It gets created using whatever account you created it with.  No matter how you start this process remotely, it won't be visible in a GUI session.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same pain trying to run "netsh.exe" on a remote host. Eventually got it working with the following code:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 10.10.10.10 -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression "C:\Program Files\program.exe"}
```

Comment: [Here's a link to the PowerShell team expressly telling you not to do that](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).